# How to reference a variable in c++ ue5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am currently working in a multithreaded environment where I need to pass a reference as a global variable. The basic structure would look something like this:

```
Worker::JoyInit(TSet<Worker>& w)

{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("w.num() = %d"), w.Num());
}
```

But the editor crashes every time I try to play it! I am not very comfortable with pointers so any quick advice would be greatly appreciated
I am calling `JoyInit` like so:

```
Worker::JoyInit(*queue);
```

and queue is defined as:

```
TSet<Worker>* queue = nullptr;
```

Comment: How do you call JoyInit? Can you show more code?

Comment: This may depend on what you passed in as an argument to `JoyInit`.

Comment: OK I edited my post with some information for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out what I did wrong.  My method call and initialization of queue variable were wrong.  I changed the code to:

```
Worker::JoyInit(queue);
```

and

```
TSet<Worker> queue;
```

and it compiles.